# Perfect numbers in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am working on a code and this is all I have so far. I am stuck at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The program for a Boolean-valued function perfect(n) that calculates and returns the Boolean value True or False according to whether the value of the parameter n is a perfect number or not, respectively.

```
def main():
    numPerfects = eval(input("How many perfect numbers do you want to find?"))
    perfectsFound=0
    possiblePerfect=1
    while(perfectsFound < numPerfects):
        if (perfect(possiblePerfect)):
            perfectsFound += 1
            print ("{0:0}}.{1:0}".format(perfectsFound, possiblePerfect))
        #end if
    #end while
#end main

main()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by checking if all the values that "can" divide an "number" add up to the double of that "number":

```
def isperfect(n):
    factors = [1]+[i for i in range(2,n+1) if n%i == 0]
    if sum(factors) == 2*n: 
        return True
    return False

for i in range(1000):
    if isperfect(i):
        print(i)
```

, the result is:

```
6
28
496
```

Comment: I received this error when I ran the code. Do you know what it means?     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kalebdill/Documents/Untitled.py", line 11, in <module>
    isperfect()
TypeError: isperfect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

Comment: Yes, but you didn't get that error from running this code. It's saying the you didn't give an argument on your call for 'isperfect()'. You must give a number to it. For example: 'isperfect(10)'.

Comment: @Chris If this answer helped you solve your problem you should accept it.